# Linq-to-SQL seeing if the are no results

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

How come my code is showing a syntax error on this block of code

```
public string getPassword()
{
   DataClasses1DataContext myDbContext = new DataClasses1DataContext(dbPath);

   var password = (from user in myDbContext.Accounts
                   where user.accnt_User == txtUser.Text
                   select user.accnt_Pass).First();

   if (password == 0) 
   { }

   return password;
}
```

I want to know if the result of query is 0, if it is 0 I will close the operation or something like that. but It keeps showing an error how would I know if the result is 0? also if you have suggestions regarding my approach feel free to put it in

Comment: And what is the type of the `accnt_Pass` field? I think it is not `int`, and your comparing it with `0`.

Comment: you want to know if the password equal a 0 ? or there's not a password for this user ?

Comment: there's not a password for this user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `.First()` will result in an exception if there is no data returned...

Calling `.FirstOrDefault()` will return `null` if there is no data

```
public string getPassword()
{
   DataClasses1DataContext myDbContext = new DataClasses1DataContext(dbPath);

   var password = (from user in myDbContext.Accounts
                   where user.accnt_User == txtUser.Text
                   select user.accnt_Pass).FirstOrDefault();

   if (password == null) 
   {
      // no data found - do whatever is needed in that case...
   }

   return password;
}
```